# jQuery ui autocomplete with different data sources

Tags: jquery, json, user-interface, custom-data-attribute

I have a form with several fields that need to have autocomplete available, and I am using the "multiple" option, so that each field can have several values chosen. I can get everything to work fine with a single data source.

Here's the issue: each field needs to have a *different* remote data source (php file outputting JSON array). I thought to use a custom `data-attribute` to list the JSON data source url.

Here is what one of my inputs look like:
    `<input type="text" name="frr" id="frr" data-searchsource="searchFrr.php" class="autofillme">`

Here is what I have for jQuery - I don't get any console errors, yet it doesn't work (autocomplete no longer works at all). If I hardcode in `"searchFrr.php"` for the `$.getJSON` request, everything works fine (using that single data source).

Any ideas how to get this working correctly? Thanks so much for looking!! :)

```
$( function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$('.autofillme').each(function() {

    $(this)
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( $(this).data("searchsource"), {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 3  ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: _“yet it doesn't work (autocomplete no longer works at all)”_ - and what happens instead …? Have you checked whether it still makes any requests at all, are there errors, …?

Comment: Have you checked what `$(this)` is at that point?

Comment: To be honest I'm not fluent in jQuery - I'm working on this as a favour. I have spent a good few hours trying to solve this issue with my limited knowledge, and extensive searching, reading documentation and looking at other similar issues on StackOverflow and elsewhere. I feel the downvotes are a bit harsh, given that I have tried to provide info as clearly as I know how, and I'm not just rolling up with no effort asking someone to write my code for me.

Comment: As to your Q: what happens instead - No errors in console, no visual change, text field remains as is. I'm unsure how to check whether requests are still being made, and will look into that, plus what $(this) is tomorrow, and edit accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I could not manage to achieve what I wanted via the methods I was attempting. I am sure someone more accomplished in jQuery would have been able to figure it out.

I did find a solution though, which allows me to use a different data source depending on which field is being typed in. This is using jQuery UI Autocomplete, with remote data source, and "multiple" option so several values can be chosen per field. I add a class of `autofillme` to each input in my form that I want to autocomplete.

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
$( function() {
  function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$('.autofillme').each(function() {

    $(this)
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( "searchDB.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term ),
            // adds an extra query string to the URL, sending the ID of the field sending the request
            field: $(this).attr('element').attr('id')
          }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 3  ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
});
```

`PHP - searchDB.php`

```
require "config.php"; // DB credentials stored here

$term = $_GET['term']; // What's been typed so far in the field

$field = $_GET['field']; // The ID of the field that's sending the request
try {
      $connection = new PDO($DB, $username, $password, $options);

        if ($field == 'field_A') {
          $array = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM columnA where value LIKE '%".$term."%'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          echo json_encode($array);
        }
        elseif ($field == 'field_B') {
          $array = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM columnB where value LIKE '%".$term."%'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          echo json_encode($array);
        }
        elseif ($field == 'field_C') {
          $array = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM columnC where value LIKE '%".$term."%'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          echo json_encode($array);
        }
        else {
          // whatever happens if no field sent
        }
      } 
      catch(PDOException $error) {

         echo "A problem has occurred fetching data";
      }
```

Ultimately this may not be a stellar solution, or particularly scalable, but it does exactly what I want - so it solves my question. Hopefully it may be useful to someone out there looking at doing a similar thing.